# I don't know what the error means?

Tags: java

```
        System.out.print("Enter Point1 X: ");
        int point1X = G51OOPInput.readInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Point1 Y: ");
        int point1Y = G51OOPInput.readInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Point2 X: ");
        int point2X = G51OOPInput.readInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Point2 Y: ");
        int point2Y = G51OOPInput.readInt();
        MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(point1X, point1Y);
        MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint(point2X, point2Y);
        MyLine line = new MyLine(p1, p2);
```

With this code, I get an error saying : 'Cannot instantiate the type MyLine' and I don't know what it means or how to fix it. Any help please?

That was from the main file, but the abstract of MyLine is here http://pastebin.com/3tRbgtge

Comment: Please show the *actual* and complete error message. Please show us the MyLine class's code.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, abstract or an interface.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - re: error comment on my deleted answer - thanks! :)

Comment: Niced choice of words, "the abstract of `MyLine` is here:".  It **is** abstract.  That's your problem.

Comment: @PaulVargas: you should be the one to post the answer since you stated this first. Do so and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Not problem! I'm studying for update my SCJP.

Answer (score 3):

Yep your MyLine class is abstract and you can't instantiate it.

```
public abstract class MyLine extends MyShape{
```

You need to instantiate a concrete subclass of it.

**Edit**
Or if MyLine is your class and you made it abstract because you did not implement all necessary methods, then edit the class, remove the abstract key word, and be sure to implement *all* the abstract methods defined in its parent class, Shape.

Answer (score 1):

`MyLine` is an `abstract` class. You cannot instantiate it. You need to create a concrete subclass of `MyLine` and instantiate that.

Comment: How and where do I do the concrete subclass?

Comment: You need to create a non-`abstract` class that extends `MyLine`. You can create it in its own file, or as a nested subclass depending on your requirements.